# How to redirect URL's in IIS

Tags: iis

I have a website setup in IIS, current working URL is     http://hr.something.com/ess

I need to have a redirect, so that if the users type in http://hr.something.com they will still end up at the /ess page.

Currently just typing in http://hr.something.com gives the default IIS landing page.

Everything i've found online talks about adding/removing trailing slashes or doing rewrites (which i dont think is what is needed here)

Apologies if there are already answers for this, but im sure im using the wrong terminologies, leading me to the wrong answers.

Answer (score 0):

you should install the iis rewrite module

and see the

https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

create the rediretly rule and you could test in iis manager

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```